# SQL Server Express dev setup - access denied whack-a-mole

Tags: sql, entity-framework, visual-studio, sql-server-express

I have a development environment in which I need to use IIS and SQL Server Express. My connection string looks like this:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" 
     connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyProject.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True" 
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

This works great when I run the app and browse to the site. Data is returned from the database and I can log into Management Studio and view that data. The problem is when I try to push a new data migration using `Update-Database`.

I then get this error message:

> Login failed for user 'AzureAD\MyAccount'

If I remove `User Instance=True` from my connection string, the `Update-Database` command suddenly works! Then I refresh my page and see the following error from all endpoints that require the database:

> CREATE DATABASE permission denied in database 'master'.

I have already tried the trick of deleting this folder. It did not solve it.

```
C:\Users\MyAccount\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Data
```

What gives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured this out so Ill leave the answer here for the next dev:

As I mentioned, my dev setup is running IIS and SQL Express.

1. Update the connection string to point to an `Initial Catalog=MyDatabase` instead of the `AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyProject.mdf`
2. Remove `User Instance=True`. Your connection string now looks like:

`Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=FullStackFitness;Integrated Security=True`

3. Create the database by running `Update-Database`.
4. Create a SQL login for the app pool account (IIS APPPOOL\ACCOUNT) dbcreator and sysadmin on the database.

I did not test it but I believe you can keep using an mdf file and still get this to work by running only steps 2 - 4.

### Troubleshooting Tips

Help troubleshooting the access denied issue came from a tip on Scott Allens [blog](http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2012/08/15/a-troubleshooting-guide-for-entity-framework-connections-amp-migrations.aspx):

> The first step I would recommend is trying to determine what connection string the framework is using, because the exception doesn’t tell you the connection string, and the connection string can be controlled by a variety of conventions, configurations, and code.
>
> To find out the connection string, I’d add some logging to a default constructor in my DbContext derived class.

```
public class DepartmentDb : DbContext 
{
    public DepartmentDb() 
    {
       Debug.Write(Database.Connection.ConnectionString);
    }
    
    public DbSet<Person> People { get; set; }
 }
```

> Run the application with the debugger and watch the Visual Studio Output window. Or, set a breakpoint and observe the ConnectionString property as you go somewhere in the application that tries to make a database connection.